# Your app uses a bad version of WebRTC, which contains security vulnerabilities. - Flutter PLay Store Console

Tags: flutter, webrtc, google-play-console

I have integrated jitsi_meet_wrapper plugin in my project and published app on google play store. I got below error message from google:

> Your app uses a bad version of WebRTC, which contains security
> vulnerabilities.

[image]

I am using:

- Flutter : 2.10.5
- Dart: 2.16.2
- jitsi_meet_wrapper: ^0.0.1
- callkeep :0.3.2

.....

Comment: Please don't put the same text multiple times into your question. That's not helpful at all.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community I have mentioned the details. I got the error from Google Play Console. Reason is not cleared. I am not using Webrtc directly instead I have used  jitsi_meet_wrapper plugin. I hope this info is enough

Answer (score 0):

Jitsi meet wrapper seems to use an old version of jitsti sdk.
Webrtc has been updated in recent version , [release note](https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet-release-notes/blob/master/CHANGELOG-MOBILE-SDKS.md) 
You may need to update the package yourself as this wrapper don't seems to be updated frequently.